# How to make an N by N matrix using python in which value for each a(i,j) is known?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

data is given like this in a text file:

A B 1 
B C -1 
A C 1 
B D 1  
D A -1 
C D 1

and the matrix has to be like: 
\   A  B  C  D 
A    0  1   1 -1 
B    1  0  -1  1
C    1 -1   0  1 
D   -1  1   1  0

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
#df = pd.read_csv('your file.txt')

s = df.pivot(*df.columns)
out = s.T.add(s,fill_value=0).fillna(0)
Out[745]: 
col1    A    B    C    D
col2                    
A     0.0  1.0  1.0 -1.0
B     1.0  0.0 -1.0  1.0
C     1.0 -1.0  0.0  1.0
D    -1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
```